# Remove metadata from XLS in LibreOffice

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, metadata

Having a XLS file I created for my father back in the day.

I am using a copy of this for myself to generate some documents I export to PDF.

Issue is that the file's metadata put my fathers name as the author in the *created by* field.

I have tried to:

- Save as new document
- Save a copy as new document
- Used File -> Properties … -> with

  - *“Apply user data”* - checked

    - Reset + Save, Save as, save copy
  - *“Apply user data”* - unchecked

    - Reset + Save, Save as, save copy

The documents always have *Created: DATE, TIME, Name* for when I created it on my fathers PC ages ago.

---

I keep it as XLS because I sometimes have to use it in MS-Office. (By USB-pin on some random computer.)

I do *not* have MS-Office available.

There is a lot of formatting etc. Some of it get mangled if I convert to ODS.

Copying the sheets (there is quite a few) to a new document mangles up some of the formulas used.

Know I can strip the metadata after export to PDF - but that is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Office did you use?
Refer to this support article about *Remove hidden data and personal information by inspecting documents, presentations, or workbooks*:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-presentations-or-workbooks-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f#ID0EBBF=Excel

Comment: The document was created with Office 2003. LibreOffice is  6.0.7.3. (And I added Linux tag)